# Yolov5 custom dataset detection

Tags: python, yolov5

I am currently trying to execute the yolov5 framework for custom dataset using roboflow blog :
https://blog.roboflow.com/how-to-train-yolov5-on-a-custom-dataset/

While executing the notebook, the following error is met with, in train.py of yolov5 git,

```
    File "train.py", line 41
logger.info(colorstr('hyperparameters: ') + ', '.join(f'{k}={v}' for k, v in hyp.items()))
                                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is the syntax wrong or could it be the intrinsic values of the variables going inside.?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using Python3 (https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/6816)

Answer (score 0):

For me, I am using Anaconda Python's latest version. I think you can try to run it in colab. After training and generating the best and last .pt file. You can install the requirements on the local computer.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MdF6x6ZmLAY

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32378831)